# How can I implement a second mycred woocommerce gateway?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good day. So I have a woocommerce store with mycred plugin installed along with mycred gateway addon. I created two mycred point types - tokens and rubies of which tokens is the default point type.
I have a snippet that allows specific products to be purchased with ONLY tokens (with mycred gateway) which means, no other payment gateways installed (paypal, rave) shows up.
I want to also enable rubies to be used to purchase ONLY specified products. The issue here is I have to clone the mycred gateway and change the id, name and classes. I am not a developer but I have tried modifying the plugin using

https://mycred.me/support/forums/topic/woocommerce-checkout-2-gateway/

However, I keep on breaking my site trying to modify other classes. I would have paid developers to do it for me but they are kind of very expensive right now and I am running a very small business. I would appreciate any help offered. Thanks.

Here is the full code of the mycred gateway

```
if ( ! defined( 'myCRED_VERSION' ) ) exit;

/**
 * WooCommerce Payment Gateway
 * Custom Payment Gateway for WooCommerce.
 * @see http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/
 * @since 0.1
 * @version 1.5
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_init_woo_gateway' ) ) :
    function mycred_init_woo_gateway() {

        if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Payment_Gateway' ) || class_exists( 'WC_Gateway_myCRED' ) ) return;

        class WC_Gateway_myCRED extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

            public $mycred;

            /**
             * Constructor
             */
            public function __construct() {

                $this->id                        = 'mycred';
                $this->icon                      = '';
                $this->has_fields                = true;
                $this->method_title              = mycred_label();
                $this->method_description        = __( 'Let users pay using points.', 'mycred' );
                $this->supports                  = array(
                    'products',
                    'refunds'
                );

                if ( ! $this->use_exchange() )
                    $this->mycred_type = get_woocommerce_currency();

                else {
                    $this->mycred_type = $this->get_option( 'point_type' );
                    if ( ! mycred_point_type_exists( $this->mycred_type ) )
                        $this->mycred_type = MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY;
                }

                $this->mycred                    = mycred( $this->mycred_type );

                // Load the settings.
                $this->init_form_fields();
                $this->init_settings();

                // Define user set variables
                $this->title                     = $this->get_option( 'title' );
                $this->description               = $this->get_option( 'description' );

                if ( $this->use_exchange() )
                    $exchange_rate = (float) $this->get_option( 'exchange_rate' );
                else
                    $exchange_rate = 1;

                if ( ! is_numeric( $exchange_rate ) )
                    $exchange_rate = 1;

                $this->exchange_rate             = $exchange_rate;
                $this->log_template              = $this->get_option( 'log_template' );
                $this->log_template_refund       = $this->get_option( 'log_template_refund' );
                $this->profit_sharing_refund_log = $this->get_option( 'profit_sharing_refund_log' );

                $this->show_total                = $this->get_option( 'show_total' );
                $this->total_label               = $this->get_option( 'total_label' );
                $this->balance_format            = $this->get_option( 'balance_format' );

                $this->profit_sharing_percent    = $this->get_option( 'profit_sharing_percent' );
                $this->profit_sharing_log        = $this->get_option( 'profit_sharing_log' );

                // Actions
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
                add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_mycred',                              array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );

            }

            /**
             * Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields
             * @since 0.1
             * @version 1.4.1
             */
            function init_form_fields() {

                // Fields
                $fields['enabled']             = array(
                    'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'    => 'checkbox',
                    'label'   => sprintf( __( 'Enable %s Payment', 'mycred' ), $this->method_title ),
                    'default' => 'no',
                    'description' => __( 'Users who are not logged in or excluded from using myCRED will not have access to this gateway!', 'mycred' )
                );
                $fields['title']               = array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Title', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'Title to show for this payment option.', 'mycred' ),
                    'default'     => __( 'Pay with myCRED', 'mycred' ),
                    'desc_tip'    => true
                );
                $fields['description']         = array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Customer Message', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'default'     => $this->mycred->template_tags_general( 'Deduct the amount from your %_plural% balance.' )
                );
                $fields['log_template']        = array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Log Template', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => $this->mycred->available_template_tags( array( 'general' ), '%order_id%, %order_link%' ),
                    'default'     => 'Payment for Order: #%order_id%'
                );
                $fields['log_template_refund'] = array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Refund Log Template', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => $this->mycred->available_template_tags( array( 'general' ), '%order_id%, %reason%' ),
                    'default'     => 'Payment refund for order #%order_id% Reason: %reason%'
                );

                // Only add exchange rate if the currecy is not set to mycred
                if ( $this->use_exchange() ) {

                    $mycred_types = mycred_get_types();
                    $fields['point_type']      = array(
                        'title'       => __( 'Point Type', 'mycred' ),
                        'type'        => 'select',
                        'label'       => __( 'Select the point type users can use to pay.', 'mycred' ),
                        'options'     => $mycred_types,
                        'default'     => MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY
                    );

                    $exchange_desc = $this->mycred->template_tags_general( __( 'How much is 1 %_singular% worth in %currency%?', 'mycred' ) );
                    $exchange_desc = str_replace( '%currency%', get_woocommerce_currency(), $exchange_desc );

                    $fields['exchange_rate']   = array(
                        'title'       => __( 'Exchange Rate', 'mycred' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'description' => $exchange_desc,
                        'default'     => 1,
                        'desc_tip'    => true
                    );
                    $fields['show_total']      = array(
                        'title'       => __( 'Show Total', 'mycred' ),
                        'type'        => 'select',
                        'label'       => $this->mycred->template_tags_general( __( 'Show the final price in %_plural% .', 'mycred' ) ),
                        'options'     => array(
                            ''           => __( 'Do not show', 'mycred' ),
                            'cart'       => __( 'Show in Cart', 'mycred' ),
                            'checkout'   => __( 'Show on Checkout Page', 'mycred' ),
                            'all'        => __( 'Show in Cart and on Checkout Page', 'mycred' )
                        ),
                        'default'     => ''
                    );
                    $fields['total_label']     = array(
                        'title'       => __( 'Label', 'mycred' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'default'     => $this->mycred->template_tags_general( __( 'Order Total in %_plural%', 'mycred' ) ),
                        'desc_tip'    => true
                    );

                }

                else {

                    $fields['point_type']      = array(
                        'title'       => __( 'Point Type', 'mycred' ),
                        'type'        => 'currency',
                        'description' => $this->mycred->plural(),
                        'default'     => $this->mycred_type
                    );

                }

                $fields['balance_format']            = array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Balance Label', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'The label to use when presenting a user their balance on the checkout / cart pages. Leave empty to hide.', 'mycred' ),
                    'default'     => 'Your Balance',
                    'desc_tip'    => false
                );
                $fields['profit_sharing_percent']    = array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Profit Sharing', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'Option to share sales with the product owner. Use zero to disable.', 'mycred' ),
                    'default'     => 0,
                    'desc_tip'    => true
                );
                $fields['profit_sharing_log']        = array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Log Template', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'Log entry template for profit sharing.', 'mycred' ) . ' ' . $this->mycred->available_template_tags( array( 'general', 'post' ) ),
                    'default'     => 'Sale of %post_title%'
                );
                $fields['profit_sharing_refund_log'] = array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Refund Log Template', 'mycred' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'Log entry template for refunds of profit shares.', 'mycred' ) . ' ' . $this->mycred->available_template_tags( array( 'general', 'post' ) ),
                    'default'     => 'Refund for order #%order_id%'
                );
                
                $this->form_fields = apply_filters( 'mycred_woo_fields', $fields, $this );

            }

            /**
             * Generate Text Input HTML.
             * @since 1.7.6
             * @version 1.0
             */
            public function generate_text_html( $key, $data ) {

                $field_key = $this->get_field_key( $key );
                $defaults  = array(
                    'title'             => '',
                    'disabled'          => false,
                    'class'             => '',
                    'css'               => '',
                    'placeholder'       => '',
                    'type'              => 'text',
                    'desc_tip'          => false,
                    'description'       => '',
                    'custom_attributes' => array(),
                );

                $data     = wp_parse_args( $data, $defaults );
                $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();

                ob_start();
?>
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row" class="titledesc">
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $field_key ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['title'] ); ?></label>
        <?php echo $this->get_tooltip_html( $data ); ?>
    </th>
    <td class="forminp">
        <?php if ( $data['type'] == 'currency' ) : $mycred = mycred( $currency ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $field_key ); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $field_key ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>" />
        <p><?php echo $mycred->plural(); ?></p>
        <?php else : ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['title'] ); ?></span></legend>
            <input class="input-text regular-input <?php echo esc_attr( $data['class'] ); ?>" type="<?php echo esc_attr( $data['type'] ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $field_key ); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $field_key ); ?>" style="<?php echo esc_attr( $data['css'] ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_option( $key ) ); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr( $data['placeholder'] ); ?>" <?php disabled( $data['disabled'], true ); ?> <?php echo $this->get_custom_attribute_html( $data ); ?> />
            <?php echo $this->get_description_html( $data ); ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php

                return ob_get_clean();

            }

            /**
             * Use Exchange
             * Checks to see if exchange is needed.
             * @since 0.1
             * @version 1.0
             */
            function use_exchange() {

                $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
                if ( mycred_point_type_exists( $currency ) || $currency == 'MYC' ) return false;
                return true;

            }

            /**
             * Admin Panel Options
             * @since 0.1
             * @version 1.1
             */
            public function admin_options() {

?>
        <h3><?php printf( __( '%s Payment', 'mycred' ), mycred_label() ); ?></h3>
        <table class="form-table">
<?php

                // Generate the HTML For the settings form.
                $this->generate_settings_html();

?>
        </table>
<?php

            }

            /**
             * Process Payment
             * @since 0.1
             * @version 1.4.3
             */
            function process_payment( $order_id ) {

                global $woocommerce;

                // Make sure we are still logged in
                if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    wc_add_notice( $this->mycred->template_tags_general( __( 'You must be logged in to pay with %_plural%', 'mycred' ) ), 'error' );
                    return;
                }

                $user_id     = get_current_user_id();

                // Make sure we have not been excluded
                if ( $this->mycred->exclude_user( $user_id ) ) {
                    wc_add_notice( $this->mycred->template_tags_general( __( 'You can not use this gateway. Please try a different payment option.', 'mycred' ) ), 'error' );
                    return;
                }

                // Grab Order
                $order       = wc_get_order( $order_id );

                $order_total = ( version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '3.0', '>=' ) ) ? $order->get_total() : $order->order_total;

                // Cost
                $cost        = $order_total;
                if ( $this->use_exchange() )
                    $cost = $this->mycred->number( ( $order_total / $this->exchange_rate ) );

                $cost        = apply_filters( 'mycred_woo_order_cost', $cost, $order, false, $this );

                // Check funds
                if ( $this->mycred->get_users_balance( $user_id, $this->mycred_type ) < $cost ) {
                    $message = apply_filters( 'mycred_woo_error_insufficient_funds', __( 'Insufficient funds.', 'mycred' ) );
                    wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
                    return;
                }

                // Let others decline a store order
                $decline     = apply_filters( 'mycred_decline_store_purchase', false, $order, $this );
                if ( $decline !== false ) {
                    wc_add_notice( $decline, 'error' );
                    return;
                }

                // Charge
                $this->mycred->add_creds(
                    'woocommerce_payment',
                    $user_id,
                    0 - $cost,
                    $this->log_template,
                    $order_id,
                    array( 'ref_type' => 'post' ),
                    $this->mycred_type
                );

                $order->payment_complete();

                // Profit Sharing
                if ( $this->profit_sharing_percent > 0 ) {

                    // Get Items
                    $items = $order->get_items();

                    // Loop though items
                    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

                        // Get Product
                        $product    = mycred_get_post( (int) $item['product_id'] );

                        // Continue if product has just been deleted or owner is buyer
                        if ( $product === NULL || $product->post_author == $user_id ) continue;

                        // Calculate Share
                        $percentage = apply_filters( 'mycred_woo_profit_share', $this->profit_sharing_percent, $order, $product, $this );
                        if ( $percentage == 0 ) continue;

                        $share      = ( $percentage / 100 ) * $item['line_total'];

                        // Payout
                        $this->mycred->add_creds(
                            'store_sale',
                            $product->post_author,
                            $this->mycred->number( $share ),
                            $this->profit_sharing_log,
                            $product->ID,
                            array( 'ref_type' => 'post' ),
                            $this->mycred_type
                        );

                    }

                }

                // Let others play
                do_action( 'mycred_paid_for_woo', $order, $user_id, $this );

                // Return the good news
                return array(
                    'result'   => 'success',
                    'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
                );

            }

            /**
             * Process Refunds
             * @since 1.5.4
             * @version 1.0.3
             */
            public function process_refund( $order_id, $amount = null, $reason = '' ) {

                $order       = wc_get_order( $order_id );

                $order_total = ( version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '3.0', '>=' ) ) ? $order->get_total() : $order->order_total;
                $user_id     = ( version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '3.0', '>=' ) ) ? $order->get_user_id() : $order->user_id;

                if ( $amount === NULL )
                    $amount = $order_total;

                $refund      = $amount;
                if ( $this->use_exchange() )
                    $refund = $this->mycred->number( ( $refund / $this->exchange_rate ) );

                $this->mycred->add_creds(
                    'woocommerce_refund',
                    $user_id,
                    0 - $refund,
                    $this->log_template_refund,
                    $order_id,
                    array( 'ref_type' => 'post', 'reason' => $reason ),
                    $this->mycred_type
                );

                $order->add_order_note( sprintf( _x( 'Refunded %s', '%s = Point amount formatted', 'mycred' ), $this->mycred->format_creds( $refund ) ) );

                // Profit Sharing
                if ( $this->profit_sharing_percent > 0 ) {

                    // Get Items
                    $items = $order->get_items();

                    // Loop though items
                    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

                        // Get Product
                        $product = mycred_get_post( (int) $item['product_id'] );

                        // Continue if product has just been deleted
                        if ( $product === NULL ) continue;

                        // Calculate Share
                        $percentage = apply_filters( 'mycred_woo_profit_share_refund', $this->profit_sharing_percent, $order, $product, $this );
                        if ( $percentage == 0 ) continue;

                        $share      = ( $percentage / 100 ) * $item['line_total'];

                        // Payout
                        $this->mycred->add_creds(
                            'store_sale_refund',
                            $product->post_author,
                            0 - $share,
                            $this->profit_sharing_refund_log,
                            $product->ID,
                            array( 'ref_type' => 'post', 'order_id' => $order_id ),
                            $this->mycred_type
                        );

                    }

                }

                // Let others play
                do_action( 'mycred_refunded_for_woo', $order, $amount, $reason, $this );

                return true;

            }

            /**
             * Thank You Page
             * @since 0.1
             * @version 1.0
             */
            function thankyou_page() {

                echo apply_filters( 'mycred_woo_thank_you_message', '<p>' . __( 'Your account has successfully been charged.', 'mycred' ) . '</p>' );

            }

        }

    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mycred_init_woo_gateway' );

/**
 * Register Gateway
 * @since 0.1
 * @version 1.0
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_register_woo_gateway' ) ) :
    function mycred_register_woo_gateway( $methods ) {

        $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_myCRED';
        return $methods;

    }
endif;
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'mycred_register_woo_gateway' );

/**
 * Available Gateways
 * "Removes" this gateway as a payment option if:
 * - User is not logged in
 * - User is excluded
 * - Users balance is too low
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @version 1.3
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_woo_available_gateways' ) ) :
    function mycred_woo_available_gateways( $gateways ) {

        if ( ! isset( $gateways['mycred'] ) ) return $gateways;

        // Easy override
        if ( defined( 'SHOW_MYCRED_IN_WOOCOMMERCE' ) && SHOW_MYCRED_IN_WOOCOMMERCE ) return $gateways;

        // Check if we are logged in
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

            unset( $gateways['mycred'] );

            return $gateways;

        }

        $point_type = $gateways['mycred']->get_option( 'point_type' );
        if ( ! mycred_point_type_exists( $point_type ) )
            $point_type = MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY;

        // Get myCRED
        $mycred     = mycred( $point_type );
        $user_id    = get_current_user_id();

        // Check if we are excluded from myCRED usage
        if ( $mycred->exclude_user( $user_id ) ) {

            unset( $gateways['mycred'] );

            return $gateways;

        }

        global $woocommerce;

        // Calculate cost in CREDs
        $currency   = get_woocommerce_currency();

        $cost       = $woocommerce->cart->total;
        if ( ! mycred_point_type_exists( $currency ) && $currency != 'MYC' )
            $cost = $mycred->number( ( $woocommerce->cart->total / $gateways['mycred']->get_option( 'exchange_rate' ) ) );

        $cost       = apply_filters( 'mycred_woo_order_cost', $cost, $woocommerce->cart, true, $mycred );

        // Check if we have enough points
        if ( $mycred->get_users_balance( $user_id, $point_type ) < $cost ) {
            $gateways['mycred']->enabled = 'no';
        }

        return $gateways;

    }
endif;
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'mycred_woo_available_gateways' );

/**
 * Add Currency
 * Inserts all registered point types as a currency in WooCommerce.
 * @since 0.1
 * @version 1.2
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_woo_add_currency' ) ) :
    function mycred_woo_add_currency( $currencies ) {

        $point_types = mycred_get_types();

        if ( ! empty( $point_types ) ) {
            foreach ( $point_types as $type_id => $label ) {

                if ( $type_id == MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY )
                    $type_id = 'MYC';

                $currencies[ $type_id ] = $label;

            }
        }

        return $currencies;

    }
endif;
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'mycred_woo_add_currency' );

/**
 * Currency Symbol
 * Appends the myCRED prefix or suffix to the amount.
 * @since 0.1
 * @version 1.2.1
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_woo_currency_symbol' ) ) :
    function mycred_woo_currency_symbol( $currency_symbols ) {

        $point_types = mycred_get_types();
        if ( ! empty( $point_types ) ) {
            foreach ( $point_types as $type_id => $label ) {

                $mycred = mycred( $type_id );
                $symbol = '';
                if ( ! empty( $mycred->after ) )
                    $symbol = $mycred->after;
                elseif ( ! empty( $mycred->before ) )
                    $symbol = $mycred->before;

                if ( $type_id == MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY )
                    $type_id = 'MYC';

                $currency_symbols[ $type_id ] = $symbol;

            }
        }

        return $currency_symbols;

    }
endif;
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbols', 'mycred_woo_currency_symbol' );

/**
 * Log Entry: Payment
 * @since 0.1
 * @version 1.4
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_woo_log_entry_payment' ) ) :
    function mycred_woo_log_entry_payment( $content, $log_entry ) {

        $order_id   = absint( $log_entry->ref_id );
        $order_link = '#' . $order_id;

        if ( function_exists( 'wc_get_order' ) ) {

            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            if ( $order !== false && is_object( $order ) )
                $order_link = '<a href="' . esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ) . '">#' . $order_id . '</a>';

        }

        $content   = str_replace( '%order_id%',   $order_id, $content );
        $content   = str_replace( '%order_link%', $order_link, $content );

        return $content;

    }
endif;
add_filter( 'mycred_parse_log_entry_woocommerce_payment', 'mycred_woo_log_entry_payment', 90, 2 );

/**
 * Log Entry: Refund
 * @since 1.5.4
 * @version 1.0
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_woo_log_entry_refunds' ) ) :
    function mycred_woo_log_entry_refunds( $content, $log_entry ) {

        $content = mycred_woo_log_entry_payment( $content, $log_entry );

        $data    = maybe_unserialize( $log_entry->data );
        $reason  = '-';
        if ( isset( $data['reason'] ) && $data['reason'] != '' )
            $reason = $data['reason'];

        $content = str_replace( '%reason%', $reason, $content );

        return $content;

    }
endif;
add_filter( 'mycred_parse_log_entry_woocommerce_refund', 'mycred_woo_log_entry_refunds', 90, 2 );

/**
 * Log Entry: Profit Share Refund
 * @since 1.5.4
 * @version 1.0
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_woo_log_entry_profit_refund' ) ) :
    function mycred_woo_log_entry_profit_refund( $content, $log_entry ) {

        $data     = maybe_unserialize( $log_entry->data );
        $order_id = '';
        if ( isset( $data['order_id'] ) && $data['order_id'] != '' )
            $order_id = '#' . $data['order_id'];

        $content  = str_replace( '%order_id%', $order_id, $content );

        $reason   = '-';
        if ( isset( $data['reason'] ) && $data['reason'] != '' )
            $reason = $data['reason'];

        $content  = str_replace( '%reason%', $reason, $content );

        return $content;

    }
endif;
add_filter( 'mycred_parse_log_entry_store_sale_refund', 'mycred_woo_log_entry_profit_refund', 90, 2 );

/**
 * Parse Email Notice
 * @since 1.2.2
 * @version 1.0.2
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_woo_parse_email' ) ) :
    function mycred_woo_parse_email( $email ) {

        if ( $email['request']['ref'] == 'woocommerce_payment' && function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_page_id' ) ) {

            if ( function_exists( 'wc_get_order' ) )
                $order = wc_get_order( (int) $email['request']['ref_id'] );
            else
                $order = new WC_Order( (int) $email['request']['ref_id'] );

            if ( isset( $order->id ) ) {

                $url     = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'order', $order->id, mycred_get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'view_order' ) ) ) );
                $content = str_replace( '%order_id%', $order->id, $email['request']['entry'] );

                $email['request']['entry'] = str_replace( '%order_link%', '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">#' . $order->id . '</a>', $content );

            }

        }

        return $email;

    }
endif;
add_filter( 'mycred_email_before_send', 'mycred_woo_parse_email', 10 );

/**
 * After Order Total
 * Potentially insert the cart cost in points and the users current balance.
 * @since 0.1
 * @version 1.3
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'mycred_woo_after_order_total' ) ) :
    function mycred_woo_after_order_total() {

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return;

        // Only available for logged in non-excluded users
        global $woocommerce;

        $available_gateways = $woocommerce->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
        if ( ! isset( $available_gateways['mycred'] ) ) return;
        
        $point_type         = $available_gateways['mycred']->get_option( 'point_type' );
        if ( $point_type === NULL )
            $point_type = MYCRED_DEFAULT_TYPE_KEY;

        $mycred             = mycred( $point_type );
        $user_id            = get_current_user_id();

        // Nothing to do if we are excluded
        if ( $mycred->exclude_user( $user_id ) ) return;

        $show_total         = $available_gateways['mycred']->get_option( 'show_total' );
        $balance            = $mycred->get_users_balance( $user_id, $point_type );
        $balance_label      = $available_gateways['mycred']->get_option( 'balance_format' );

        // If we should show the total in points
        if ( ( $show_total == 'both' || $show_total == 'all') 
            || ( $show_total == 'cart' && is_cart() ) 
            || ( $show_total == 'checkout' && is_checkout() ) 
        ) {

            // Make sure myCRED is not the currency used
            $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();
            if ( ! mycred_point_type_exists( $currency ) && $currency != 'MYC' ) {

                // Apply Exchange Rate
                $cost    = $mycred->number( ( $woocommerce->cart->total / $available_gateways['mycred']->get_option( 'exchange_rate' ) ) );
                $cost    = apply_filters( 'mycred_woo_order_cost', $cost, $woocommerce->cart, true, $mycred );
                

?>
<tr class="total">
    <th><strong><?php echo $mycred->template_tags_general( $available_gateways['mycred']->get_option( 'total_label' ) ); ?></strong></th>
    <td>
        <div class="current-balance order-total-in-points">
            <strong class="<?php if ( $balance < $cost ) echo 'mycred-low-funds'; else echo 'mycred-funds'; ?>"<?php if ( $balance < $cost ) echo ' style="color:red;"'; ?>><?php echo $mycred->format_creds( $cost ); ?></strong> 
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php

            }

        }

        // If we should show the users balance
        if ( ! empty( $balance_label ) ) {

?>
<tr class="total">
    <th><strong><?php echo $mycred->template_tags_general( $balance_label ); ?></strong></th>
    <td>
        <div class="current-balance">
            <?php echo $mycred->format_creds( $balance ); ?>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php

        }

    }
endif;
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'mycred_woo_after_order_total' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total',  'mycred_woo_after_order_total' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured this out already...

1. Go to POINTS > Add-Ons
2. Activate the GATEWAY Add-On
3. Go WooCommerce > Payments
4. Slide the Purple Bar to Enable myCRED – Pay with myCRED
5. Click the SETUP button to the right of "Let users pay using points"

Configure your settings for Paying With Points and that should do it.